# jQuery: textarea default value disppear on click

Tags: jquery, textarea, onclick

I want a textarea with some default text.  When the user clicks in the textarea
the default text should be deleted. How can I make value of a textarea disappear on click?

I want it exactly like this, http://www.webune.com/forums/20101025cgtc.html

But I wish it made in jQuery.

```
<textarea id="textarea">This should be removed..</textarea>
```

Comment: If it works in plain JavaScript, why complicate it with jQuery?

Comment: @DavidThomas I want to have the text "this should be removed.." not in a javascript variable but in the html, and i prefer jquery better

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use this as its a bit more generic - it will clear out the element's value on focus, but return the element's value to the default value if empty.

```
$("#textarea")
  .focus(function() {
        if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        }
  })
  .blur(function() {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
        }
});
```

Comment: html5 now has the placeholder attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this even without JavaScript by using [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_placeholder.asp).

But you should be aware that not every browser supports it yet. In this case you can use for instance this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder

Answer (score 5):

Very simple non-jQuery-dependent solution:

```
<textarea onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">Hello World</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$('#txt')
    .focusin(function() {
        if ( this.value == 'Write something...' ) {
            this.value = '';    
        }
    })
    .focusout(function() {
        if ( this.value == '' ) {
            this.value = 'Write something...';    
        }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/g7UKN/1/

---

**Update:**

This should do it:

```
$('#txt')
    .each(function() {
        $(this).data('default', this.value);
    })
    .focusin(function() {
        if ( this.value == $(this).data('default') ) {
            this.value = '';    
        }
    })
    .focusout(function() {
        if ( this.value == '' ) {
            this.value = $(this).data('default');    
        }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/g7UKN/2/

Comment: this works how i wish although one thing remains it should check the default value for "Write something...", so if i do: <textarea>BLABLA</textarea> then it should check for the "BLABLA" and not "write something..."

Comment: @Karem Choose Scott's answer. He uses the `defaultValue` property which stores the initial value of the TEXAREA element. So, `data('default')` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#textarea').click(function(){
     if($(this).val() == "This should be removed.."){
          $(this).val() = "";
     }
});
```

//edit

```
var defaultTextAreaValue = "This should be removed..";
$('#textarea').focus(function(){
     if($(this).val() == defaultTextAreaValue){
         $(this).val("");
     }
});
$('#textarea').blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == defaultTextAreaValue){
          $(this).val(defaultTextAreaValue);
      }
});
```

Comment: You should use `.blur` and `.focus` as one can enter and leave the textarea using tabs. Also `$(this).val() = "";` should be `$(this).val("");`

Comment: @Aleksi your right I just tested my own suggestion and wondered why it doesnt work :-)

Comment: I want the textarea to show "This should be removed.." on blur again, if nothing has been entered. Just like the example. Also, the "This should be removed.." should be checked for in the default value(as in my case the default value of the txtarea wont be the same)

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below snippet. First time you click on the text area it empties the content.

```
$('#textarea').focus(function(){
 $(this).empty();
});
```

Comment: It would be a shame to populate a textarea with a bunch of text, then focus a different element, then come back and again focus the textarea only to watch all your entered text disappear :-(

Comment: agree. I posted this almost 5 yrs back :)

Answer (score 0):

You need two handlers, one for when the element gets focus and one for when it loses it.  When it gets focus, check to see if the value is only space characters and, if so, set the value to the default.

```
$('#textarea').focus( function(){
        var $this =$(this);
        if($this.val() == 'This should be removed..'){
             $this.val('');
        }
}).blur(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().match(/^\s*$/) { // matches only spaces or nothing
             $this.val('This should be removed..');
        }
});
```

Comment: as said to the others, the "This should be removed.." should be in the <textarea>This should be removed..</textarea> so it checks for the default value in the textarea

Answer (score 0):

And if someone wants to do this trick on a ajax loaded textareas you can achieve this with the `.live()` event ;)

```
$('#textarea').live('focusin',function () {
        if (this.value === 'leDefault ...') {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $('.larger').live('focusout',function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = 'leDefault';
        }
    });
```