# textarea placeholder clear on focus

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to implement basic placeholder logic with jquery for textarea.. But there is one small issue I couldnt figure out how to fix it. Here is the html ;

```
<textarea class="commentInput" rows="1" cols="50" title="Say something...">
    Say something...
</textarea>
```

and javascript is ;

```
$('.commentInput').live('focus', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});

$('.commentInput').live('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).attr('title') != '') {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).attr('rows', 1);
    }
});
```

It's all working fine but one case it's broken.. Let say I type "Say something..." to textarea, and just click to somewhere else in html, and then when i focus back to textarea it's clear the text because of jquery focus event matches the value of textarea and title of text area..

How can i solve it or anyother idea?
Thanks.

Comment: couldnt understand the problem ur facing

Comment: you want to do it for IE right? There are a lot PlugIn's for that. For example: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder-js/ or https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059732/jquery-textarea-default-value-disppear-on-click/5059842#5059842

Comment: @ScottE I check your link but your solution has the same issue?

Comment: @tylerdurden - nope - it's checking for a defaultValue, which is the text that stored inside the textarea on page load.

Comment: I tried that solution as well but it didn't work. That example removed the text if you enter 'This should be removed..' into the text area. But in this question, it is asked not to remove the text if user writes that text into text area. Here is the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/melih/Z5eSP/

Comment: @ScottE ohh i see the point, ur checking objects not the values ===, thanks man for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a flag `isDirty` on the text area element and set the flag's value on `onKeyUp` event of text area according to these rules:

- If there is a text inside the text area, then the user must have entered it so set isDirty to true;
- If the text area is empty, then set `isDirty` to false

**UPDATE:** I found a bug and following rule is added to remove that bug. When you selected the text with mouse, right clicked on it and cut the text; since there were no `keyup` events fired the `isDirty` flag remained true and functionality was lost.

Like this:

```
$('.commentInput').live('keyup', function() {
    var taObj = $(this);
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        taObj.data('isDirty', false);
    } else {
        taObj.data('isDirty', true);
    }     
});
```

Then use `isDirty` flag to determine whether text should be modified or not:

```
$('.commentInput').live('focus', function() {
    var taObj= $(this);

    if (!taObj.data('isDirty') && taObj.val() == taObj.attr('title')) {
        taObj.val('');
    }
});

$('.commentInput').live('blur', function() {
    var taObj = $(this);

    // Following check is made to make sure text was not removed with a mouse action
    if(taObj.val() == '') {
        taObj.data('isDirty', false);
    }

    if (!taObj.data('isDirty') && taObj.val() == '' && taObj.attr('title') != '') {
        taObj.val(taObj.attr('title')).attr('rows', 1);
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle example demonstrating this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/melih/WXxtg/2/

Comment: This isn't a particularly good solution. Instead of using a global `isDirty` vairable, use `jQuery.data()` instead to store the flag for that element. Done this way, you're not polluting the global namespace, and you can do this with multiple elements.

Comment: @JamWaffles You're right, I didn't feel completely right defining a global variable but then shouldn't I use a global jQuery object to keep that value? Perhaps I should use more about jQuery.data(). Thanks.

Comment: Here's the docs link if you haven't found it already: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you want the textarea to do and the javascript to do to it. The first code will clear the textarea if the text within the textarea is the same as the title you've given to the textarea.  If I understand what you wrote - shouldn't you just get rid of the focus event code?

Comment: What i want to do is when user input some text to textarea, just keep it in the textarea whether focus to textarea or not, but if textarea is empty then place text like "Say something...", the problem is if user input "Say something..." and unfocus on textarea for a while then if user click back to textarea it clears "Say something..." text which user already input, act like a it's placeholder text so clears area for new inputs..